# having trouble inserting a value into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm creating a hash function and for some reason i cant use the np.insert function. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and need a bit of help.

```
lis = np.arange(1,13)
key = np.array([18, 41, 22, 44, 59, 32, 31, 73])

# h(x) = x mod 13

for i in range(len(key)):
    slot = key[i] % 13
    np.insert(lis, slot, key[i])
print(lis)
```

lis returns

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html): "Note that insert does not occur in-place: a new array is returned".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.insert` creates a new array that is, it does not manipulate `lis` it creates a copy of `lis` & manipulates that. So if you want to store the results back into `lis` try the following

```
lis = np.arange(1,13)
key = np.array([18, 41, 22, 44, 59, 32, 31, 73])

# h(x) = x mod 13

for i in range(len(key)):
    slot = key[i] % 13
    lis = np.insert(lis, slot, key[i])
    
print(lis)
```

This gives,

`[ 1  2 41  3  4 31 44 32 73  5 59 18  6  7 22  8  9 10 11 12]`